# Authenticate with Box Developer Edition using box-python-sdk

Tags: certificate, access-token, box

I want to authenticate to Box Developer Edition using [box-python-sdk](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk), this way:

```
auth = JWTAuth(
    client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    enterprise_id='YOUR_ENTERPRISE_ID',
    rsa_private_key_file_sys_path='CERT.PEM',
    store_tokens=your_store_tokens_callback_method,
)
```

(1) I have created a private and public key using the [App Auth instructions](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-auth), and decrypted the private key. How do I get the CERT.PEM?

(2) What is the your_store_tokens_callback_method supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

`cert.pem` should be a path to a file that is your private key.

`your_store_tokens_callback_method` should be a lambda that runs and persists the tokens you get back from Box so you can make additional authenticated calls.

Check out https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/1b2d19662e904a2cc850dab2c66ee122c3b3e20e/README.rst#get-the-authorization-url for an example of `store_tokens`. It also seems that given the docs this parameter is optional.

```
def store_tokens(access_token, refresh_token):
    # store the tokens at secure storage (e.g. Keychain)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please write a simple your_store_tokens_callback_method example?

Comment: @user2667358, I've updated my answer with an example from the docs. Helpful?