# Box Python SDK for Developer/Enterprise: Clarifying JWT Authentication

Tags: python, box-api

https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/1b2d19662e904a2cc850dab2c66ee122c3b3e20e/README.rst#get-the-authorization-url states:

```
auth = JWTAuth(
     client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
     client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
     enterprise_id='YOUR_ENTERPRISE_ID',
     jwt_key_id='YOUR_JWT_KEY_ID',
     rsa_private_key_file_sys_path='CERT.PEM',
     store_tokens=your_store_tokens_callback_method,
     )
```

The first 3 arguments are self-explanatory.

4: `jwt_key_id` : where does this come from?  Is this the same thing as the public key id that goes in the JWT header?  A similar question ([Authenticate with Box Developer Edition using box-python-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645796/authenticate-with-box-developer-edition-using-box-python-sdk)) doesn't list this argument.

5: I have a path to the private key file; when I run this script it returns an error, `Password was not given but private key is encrypted.`  A community answer here  https://community.box.com/t5/Box-Developer-Forum/Setting-password-for-private-key-when-using-JWTAuth-via-box/td-p/19407 suggests the need for another parameter, so I've added:
   `rsa_private_key_passphrase = 'my_passphrase'` as another argument to JWTAuth.    Is this correct?

6: The `store_tokens` argument looks optional, so I'm assuming I can put `store_tokens=None` without kittens dying, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4: You are correct in that `jwt_key_id` is the same as the 8 characters long **Public Key ID** found in your application's configuration settings.

5: For the `rsa_private_key_file_sys_path` you have to enter the absolute path to the **private_key.pem** file.

6: Yes, `store_tokens` is not mandatory and you can remove that. Instead, replace it with `rsa_private_key_passphrase` which is needed for JWT Authentication.

**IMPORTANT:** `rsa_private_key_passphrase` must be in bytes so make sure the format is `rsa_private_key_passphrase = b'my_passphrase'`.

Hopefully, that clears things up.